# how to read rows?

Tags: bash, scripting, csh, tcsh

I'm trying to read first row from the `file`

```
> source ./rank file
```

using this script

```
set line = ($<)  <- inside rank
```

but when I enter

`echo $line` I receive nothing, how can I change it? thanks in advance

Comment: You do know that csh was never intended for writing scripts with? It's supposed to be an interactive shell,

Answer (score 1):

Since csh is brain-dead, you'll have to do something like this:

```
set line = `head -n 1 filename`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's built-in in Bash as:

```
read -r line < filename
```

Comment: Thanks, added clarification that my answer was for Bash.

Comment: `set line=\`head -n 1 filename\``

Answer (score 0):

```
set line = `cat file | sed 1q`
```